Cannot resume system tests Rails
I'm trying to complete system tests for a 2017 Rails project before I start updating it.
It's Rails 5.0.1.rc2 with ruby 2.4.1p111.
gem 'webdrivers' (... 4.1.2)
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.5"
  gem 'capybara-email'
  etc

Due to the dependencies, it's stuck at Chrome 114.0.5735.90, which stopped working 2 weeks ago apparently due to Google removing all links.
Current version of Firefox doesn't work with the antiquated version of Capybara, and I can't seem to successfully install any older browser versions (Chrome, Firefox, Chromium). Absolutely nothing works.
Should I just cancel writing tests until the site is updated then, because there is absolutely no way left to configure it?

Your best bet is definitely to update the application given that rails 5.0 fell out of support 6 years ago. Getting up to at least 6.1 should not be too difficult as long as you follow the appropriate migration path. See Upgrading Rails

If you have a lot of tests that could run without JS you could switch to the simple Rack::Test driver instead of selenium to get some of the tests running. However it might be a better use of time to just "take the plunge" and update to Rails 6 and then try to get the tests running even if its not ideal to update without test coverage and knowing what will break/was already broken.
